# Display other calendars in calendar app

Tags: sync, calendar, google-calendar

In my google calendar I created some new calendars. How do I get them to show in my "Calendar" app on Android? I'm using the stock one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer applies to 4.4 (Kit Kat) and "Calendar" version 201404xxx. Although I am guessing it will apply to most other versions.

When I click on the menu in the Calendar app I have two options that may be relevant

1: "Calendars to display". I can choose from all the calendars connected to my various accounts including shared calendars and birthdays etc...

2: "Settings". I have the ability to add new accounts

Comment: I don't see the option "Calendars to display" where are you looking? I'm using Kitkat 4.4.2 and Calendar 15.0.A.2.0

Comment: Do you have the option of updating your Calendar app in the Play store to the latest version?

Comment: I did a factory reset and now the Calendar is displaying properly with the default settings. Maybe the firmware was corrupt and it screwed it up.